psql error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
I was installing postgres on macos sonoma (apple M1 chip) and after installing, then starting the service and finally running psql in the terminal I ran into this error
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

Steps taken to arrive at this error:

$ brew install postgresql
$ brew services start postgresql

When I run $ brew services list there's this error

Didn't find a specific answer but I resolved the error as below (in the answer)

To install postgresql:

$ brew install postgresql this installs the latest stable version of postgresql available
Run initdb to initialize a database cluster $ initdb /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14
Start (or restart) the postgres service $ brew services start postgresql

Running $ brew services list should show a successful running instance (shown in screenshot below)

TIP: To see the errors logged when running the service you can open the logs stored in postgresql@14.log
$ vi /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log

(That's how I found the specific error I was seeing when listing the service and a potential solution)

Go to initdb documentation
